# How to improve speed sorting by datetime field from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have a table of Products which contains hundreds of thousands of records. The basic table structure is like so:

```
ProductID (int pk) | ObjectID (int fk) | ProductTitle | Price
101                | 5005              | Toothbrush   | 1.50
```

I have another table for Objects which stores information about different objects, but mainly who they were created by and when.

```
ObjectID (int pk) | DateCreated (datetime)  | UserID
5005              |  2017-11-16 13:00:00    | 50
```

The following query selecting Products runs in half a second:

```
SELECT 
  p.* 
FROM 
  dbo.Products p 
ORDER BY 
  ProductID DESC
```

This following query takes almost 3.5 seconds

```
SELECT 
  p.*
FROM
  dbo.Products p
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Objects o ON
  o.ObjectID = p.ObjectID
ORDER BY
  o.DateCreated DESC
```

`ObjectID` in the `Products` table has been setup as a foreign key to the `Objects` table. It also has a unique index on it.

The `DateCreated` field in `Objects` has also been indexed.

Why is the second query running 5 times slower just because I'm ordering by a `DateTime` field from another table? I know that ordering by an `int` is meant to be faster, especially as its clustered, but I didn't expect the difference to be this huge.

Any suggestions please? I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: How long does the 2nd query take without the order by clause?

Comment: @DanBracuk without the order by clause, it runs as fast as the 1st query. Really quick.

Answer (score 2):

To really understand what is happening, you need to look at the execution plans.  However, the results are not surprising.

The first query is faster because -- presumably -- the query can use an index on the table for the `order by`.  I wouldn't be surprised if the id were a primary key, making the ordering even more efficient.

The second query is slower because the `order by` is probably doing an actual sort.  This is often needed when joining tables together.

It is possible that an index on `Objects(DateCreated, ObjectId)` would be a bit more efficient.  Whether SQL Server decides to use it depends on the statistics of the tables.

Comment: The index is actually on `DateCreated, ObjectID` together and its far slower than just ordering by `ProductID` for the given reasons. But 5 times slower is just not good enough and I'm struggling to make it work.

Comment: @volumeone . . . I think you would need to store the creation date in the product table, if you want to speed it up -- or use a materialized view with an index on the created by column.

Comment: I think you are right Gordon thank you for the excellent suggestion. Except that the underlying Products table is contanstly being added to - something that Microsoft say doesn't suit a view well. I'm not sure if thats true as I don't use views at all. Will give it a try though.

Comment: So Objects is one giant table that every other table has a FK to? And its only purpose is to maintain creation information?

Comment: @SMor that's correct. it has a few others fields about the Object like DateUpdated as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sadly a view doesn't work because the query that gets all the data from `Objects` and `Products` also references information held in another database. Only two part names are allowed in views. For now im stuck.